# Write file to server disk instead of downloading

Tags: php

I generate an excel like this:

```
<?php
$file="test.xls";
$test="<table border=1><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $test;
?>
```

it works splendid. Instead of it downloading to the clients computer, can I have it write to the folder in the server?

Comment: file_put_contents...?

Comment: Above header use [`file_put_contents()`](http://uk.php.net/file_put_contents), next time please search the docs before asking.

Comment: HTML !== XLS unless you have PHP's automagic extension enabled to magically create an Excel BIFF file from HTML markup

Comment: i did search. everything came up telling me to use a class

Comment: this works great though. post as answer please

Comment: that's not an excel file, that's a text file with html.  I recommend [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) if you actully want an excel file

Comment: @user2287474 Do you need the `header` to be included in the file as well, or just to write the contents of `$test`?

Comment: i query some data from a mysql table, which in fact is an HTML table. I just need to take that string of HTML and write it as an excel file to the disk. This way works so far. if there's a better way that doesn't include installing any extensions onto the server, then I'd love to check it out.

Comment: Open Office will open this file correctly. Microsoft Office will open it as well but it will complain that this file is of the wrong type. It may confuse your users.

Comment: @user2287474 Check out what I posted below. Give it a whirl.

Comment: since you are doing no real formatting write a csv, this will be compatible with most spreadsheet programs; smaller files as well,. it a very narrow scope to say it works for you on your computer then expect that to be the case for a global audience.

Comment: It'll work great up until the point that MS Excel says that the file isn't the correct format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to write data to file, and using the code you provided, am offering a **suggestive** answer.
No downvoting now folks, it's a suggestive answer and easier to post than an actual suggestion.

Note: `a` switch, will `append` to file and the `\n` will make a new line.

```
<?php
$file = fopen('test.xls', 'a') or die("Unable to open file for output");
$test="<table border=1><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>\n";
fwrite($file, $test) or die("Unable to write to file");
fclose($file);
echo "$test"; // echo the output
exit();
?>
```